# How to depict stacked cards with mermaid diagrams?

Tags: mermaid

Oftentimes in system design flowcharts I want to depict that multiple instances of a service will be deployed in a region of a cloud computing service. For instance, there might be one instance deployed per availability zone in a region. I usually represent this by showing several overlapped cards. Only the top card is fully visible, and it specifies the properties of the service, which the reader can assume are identical for the other cards that aren't fully shown. The non-top cards may only show, for instance, the name of the availability zone in which each is deployed. See the example below.

Is there a way to depict this with mermaid chart syntax?

[image]